# Ambiguous Column name in Sql expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado

I have two tables; they are joined by relationship detail on a column name via Delphi ado link

1st table has bunch of data and a fileref as key 1, 
2nd table has rows of data and a fileref as key 2

1st table has other information but one fileref value, 
2nd table hold many fileref values but different accounts

Table 1:
id, fileref, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, accno, 7, 8, 9, etc, etc...

table 2:
id, fileref, accno

```
  SELECT * FROM vtindex a
  JOIN vi_accno b
  ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
  WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')
```

Above is the query where i get the ambiguous error

the idea is that if I dont find the accno is table 1 it must try and find it in table 2

hope this makes sense and whats wierd is that if i run the query inside MSSMS the query returns results without errors

Comment: change it to SELECT a.*, b.*

Comment: @RichBenner doesnt work m8

Comment: I've just posted as an answer, take a look and see if it solves it.

Comment: Are you **absolutely certain** that your AdoQuery's Sql.Text property contains the exact SQL statement you quote in your q?  Reason I ask is that by constructing it using Sql.Add() it is quite easy to introduce syntax errors that are caught by MS SSMS.

Comment: Okay it solved it by renaming table 2 names to viid, vifileref, viaccno then using all the suggestions from everyone here it worked, so THANK YOU ALL for all the great answers and help thus far @ RichBenner @ MartynA @ JoeC @ VahidFarahmandian

Comment: if i could i would accept all you answers as answers because each one had a piece that helped me, THANK YOU...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to declare your columns, something like this;

```
SELECT
     a.ID A_ID
    ,a.fileref A_fileref
    ,a.Field1 A_Field1
    ,a.Field2 A_Field2
    ,a.accno A_Accno
    ,b.id B_ID
    ,b.fileref B_fileref
    ,b.accno B_accno
FROM vtindex a
JOIN vi_accno b
    ON a.fileref = b.fileref
WHERE a.AccNo like '%123456789%'
    OR b.accno like '%123456789%'
```

If you only want to declare some then do this;

```
SELECT
     a.*
    ,b.id B_ID
    ,b.fileref B_fileref
    ,b.accno B_accno
FROM vtindex a
JOIN vi_accno b
    ON a.fileref = b.fileref
WHERE a.AccNo like '%123456789%'
    OR b.accno like '%123456789%'
```

Your issue is that you're using fields like `id`, `fileref` and `accno` more than once (from each table) and the names are clashing. If you change the names on your table that only has 3 records then you can get away with leaving table a as-is.

Comment: This solved my problem, i renamed the fields on the 2nd table and ran using this query : SELECT a.*, b.* FROM vtindex a JOIN vi_accnot b ON b.vifileref = a.FileRef WHERE (a.AccNo like ''%'+edit1.text+'%'') or (b.viaccno like ''%'+edit1.Text+'%'')

Comment: so infact everyone helped to the direction to which i got the answer so thanks ALL

Comment: just to be clear his reference to "If you change the names on your table that only has 3 records then you can get away with leaving table a as-is." was the answer im clicking to...

Answer (score 2):

Just try replacing `*` with explicit column names and define unique aliases for each of the columns. This will solve the ambiguity error. Following is an example:

**Updated:**

```
SELECT a.*,b.Id as b_Id, b.Fileref as b_Fileref, b.accno as b_accno FROM vtindex a
JOIN vi_accno b
ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')
```

As `@Joe C` commented too, we think you do not need to send `FileRef` and `b.Id` columns inside `vi_accno` to the output, if our assumption is right, then you can remove them from your Select and simplify it as follow:

```
SELECT a.*, b.accno as b_accno FROM vtindex a
JOIN vi_accno b
ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')
```

Comment: yikes thats alot of column references, isnt there an easier way

Comment: There are free tools that make this easier.  For SSMS I sometimes use Apex Sql Complete to automatically create the select list.

Comment: @Troz you can use third party tools such as 'Apex' or 'RedGate SQL Toolbelt'. Or you can select your query, then right click on it and select 'Design Query in Editor'. These options will help you to manage the columns and their aliases.

Comment: well i thought i was clever and tried 'SELECT a.*, b.fileref as bfileref, b.accno as baccno FROM vtindex a
JOIN vi_accno b
ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')'  but no luck ambiguous again

Comment: would it be easier if i move accno a to accno b, then just query b using join on fileref, problem is that, there is datafileds linked to column names so if i start changing column name by alias then the program wont read the data to the fields @JoeC

Comment: @Troz please add your tables DDL statement, so that I can rewrite your query and solve it.

Comment: Sorry Vahid, im no SQL expert im learning by example at this present moment, what do you mean by DDL statement. do you mean list all the table fields ? for each table ?

Comment: @Troz I mean your Create Table statements.

Comment: TABLE1: SELECT ID, FileRef, cnum, Month, Type, Typei, PropDesc, AccNo, person, client, idno, Consultant, Memo, qclose, vtdate
FROM vtindex

Comment: TABEL2: SELECT ID, Fileref, accno from vi_accno

Comment: @Troz I have updated my answer, please check to see if it is resolved.

Comment: I think what he is saying is he needs one field called accno

Comment: Sorry Vahid the updated answer didnt help check the suggestion from @Richbenner but your sql querys helped alot so thank you...

Answer (score 2):

You have the same column name in both tables, so using * pulls both and the names conflict.  In SSMS you are allowed to do that as you are only viewing the results on screen but as soon as you send the data to a destination that expects column names to be unique you will get an error.  You will have to explicitly name the columns you want in your select list.

Also, based on your question I believe you will want to use coalesce(b.accno, a.accno).  This will use the accno from A only if accno is null in B.

EDIT: Based on comments I believe here is the specific syntax I was referring to.  Note how coalesce solve the problem of column aliases by having only one field with the name you want.

```
SELECT ID, FileRef, cnum, Month, Type, Typei, 
       PropDesc, Coalesce(a.accno, b.accno) AccNo, person, client, idno,        
       Consultant, Memo, qclose, vtdate 
    FROM vtindex a
    Join vi_accno b ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
    WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')
```

Comment: ambiguous column name id, i then remove id from the sql then it complains about ambiguous column name fileref ? lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM vtindex a
    JOIN vi_accno b
    ON b.fileref = a.FileRef
    WHERE (a.AccNo like '%123456789%') or (b.accno like '%123456789%')
```

Comment: This will give the same error as accno exists in both a and b.

Comment: this doesnt work "the column prefix 'a' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query"

Comment: Please check the column names in the where clause, I think the column names not matched.

Comment: sorry for i forgot i reverted back to a previous query, it gives the same ambigious result

Comment: exact code:      form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('SELECT a.*,b.* FROM vtindex a');
      form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('JOIN vi_accno b');
      form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('ON a.fileref = b.FileRef');
      form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('WHERE (a.AccNo like ''%'+edit1.text+'%'') or (b.accno like ''%'+edit1.Text+'%'')');

Comment: I suggest you post the contents of AdoQuery1.Sql.Text **after** you have done the Add()s.  I think your WHERE clause is likely wrong ....  Btw, there is absolutely no need for all those Add()s.  You can construct the SQL in code and then do a direct assignment to the Sql.Text property - it is far less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that your problem is arising not so much from the Sql you're attempting to use, but the way you are attempting to construct it, using the completely unnecessary and error-prone SQL.Add().

The code below executes correctly and without complaint or error of any sort in D7 against 2 tables in a Sql Server 2014 database.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : String;
begin
  // WARNING: Do not use this Sql in a live application
  // There is a risk of Sql-Injection because  the Sql includes the
  // contents of Edit1.Text.  Use a parameterised query instead!
  S := 'select a.*, b.*'#13#10;
  S := S + 'from TableA a join TableB b'#13#10;  // the #13#10 can be replaced by a single space, 
  //  if you prefer
  S := S + 'on a.fileref = b.fileref'#13#10;
  S := S + 'where (a.accno like ''%' + Edit1.Text + '%'')'#13#10;
  S := S + 'or (b.accno like ''%' + Edit1.Text + '%'')'#13#10;

  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := S;
  AdoQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Note the use of single-quotes throughout, no double-quotes.

**IMPORTANT** Constructing Sql directly from the contents of TEdit controls renders your app liable to `Sql Injection` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should use parameterised Sql instead.  However,
having said that, the routine in AdoDB.Pas which parses the Sql to create the parameters, TAdoCommand.ParseSql *seems* to be broken in D7-Delphi Seattle because it seems incapable of recognising a parameter embedded in a `LIKE' construct which involves a string expression.  A way around that might be to define a Stored Proc on the server which executes the SQL with parameters supplied at run-time from the application.

So, my guess is that because you are using SQL.Add(), in fact you're not constructing the Sql you think you are.  I suspect that what the error you are getting is actually trying to tell you is that `Edit1.Text` is ambiguous - depending on your exact actuall Sql, possibly the Sql parser thinks Edit1.Text is the name of a column.

The Sql DDL for TableA and TableB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileRef] [int] NULL,
    [AccNo] [varchar](32) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileRef] [int] NULL,
    [AccNo] [varchar](32) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with SQL.Add, where is the OP saying he does this?. On the other hand never construct SQL if you don't have to. Your code sample is prone to SQL injection, please adjust it (people will read your answer and copy/paste without thinking). Always  (and I mean ALWAYS) use parameters...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I will adjust answer in a mo.  Meanwhile, where?  In a comment by the OP to the answer by DineshDB "exact code: form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('SELECT a.*,b.* FROM vtindex a'); form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('JOIN vi_accno b'); form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('ON a.fileref = b.FileRef'); form3.adoquery1.SQL.Add('WHERE (a.AccNo like ''%'+edit1.text+'%'') or (b.accno like ''%'+edit1.Text+'%'')'); "

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  Btw, I agree that there's nothing wrong *in principle* with SQL.Add(), it just seems to feature inordinately frequently in SO qs to do with erroneous SQL.

Comment: Ah missed that, should have been in the question ;)

Comment: it wasn't the edit1.text if was the same column names from table1 -> table2 i was under the impression that they had to be the same names on order to create a relationship between the 2 tables from within delphi ide, but you dont need to when you link the 2 tables together inside IDE the name can be completely different